# Multi-cURL 5000 URLs

Tags: php, mysql, curl, limit, file-get-contents

I need to check for broken images with db entries. So now I am selecting all the items from table and using CURL to check it is broken or not. I have almost 5000 items in DB and CURL is taking lot of time. For one result, it is showing the total time as 0.07 seconds. My table structure is the following :

```
+----+----------------------------------------+
| id |               image_url                |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | http://s3.xxx.com/images/imagename.gif |
|  2 | http://s3.xxx.com/images/imagename.gif |
|  3 | http://s3.xxx.com/images/imagename.gif |
|  4 | http://s3.xxx.com/images/imagename.gif |
+----+----------------------------------------+
```

So is there any other idea to check for broken images?. I think I cannot use LIMITS here as I need to check for all items and then print the result. I have user file_get_contents() but it is also taking lot of time.

Comment: divide and conquer :) maybe checking with ajax dividing it will be faster or few scripts that check only part of data. Depends if you want to save checking results or not.

Comment: I am storing the data to an array and is outputting it in a report

Comment: Do you have lots of duplicate URLs, like in your sample data? Use `DISTINCT` to suppress duplicates.

Comment: no. no duplicate URLs at all. :(

Comment: Who owns the server `s3.xxx.com` ? If you have a way to get the `/images/` content list, you can load it in a table and run a single join query.

Comment: @LeGEC The server probably prohibits directory listing.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is the following:

1. Use multi_curl to cURL the images in parallell.
2. Specify header only (as you're not interested in the image data) and if the status code is anything but 200 OK (or 302/Found), then the image does not exist.
3. Chunk the 5000 items first, don't run them all with multi_curl. About 50-100 items at a time is fine.

Comment: What are you going to do with the broken image links? Is your goal to delete them from the DB?

Comment: wouldn't a simpler way be to extract on your side the list of file names, and send it to the admin so he can run a `ls` against them ?

Comment: @AlwinAugustin Is the server yours or is it an external site?

Comment: @silkfire anyway I resolved this. Not by CURL. I have a cron that checks for missing images and send mails. so now I am inserting all the images missing in a daily basis to DB and going to prepare reports from it. Thanks man  :)

Comment: I used this: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/ as a reference to achieve a similar thing.